# Publish Blazor Server-Side .Net 8 To IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

recently I've tried publish my first Blazor Server-Side to IIS but it didn't work like I expected. I've created a folder `inetpub\wwwroot\testPublish` and then made an application (right click) `Default Web Site` and navigate the physical path to the created folder earlier. After that I publish my solution from the Visual Studio to the setup above.

When I tried to browse `'myservername'/testPublish` this happened [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYSMr.png)

What am I missing here?

All my page when I tried to navigate it skip the `testPublish` it directly goes e.g`'myservername'/home`. When I added `'myservername'/testPublish/home` then only it works. Including a function that lead to a controller it become `404 - Page not found`.

`Program.cs`

```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();
```

`App.razor`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="myPage.styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@InteractiveServer" />

    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My solution consist of services, controllers and components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> recently I've tried publish my first Blazor Server-Side to IIS but it
> didn't work like I expected. I've created a folder
> inetpub\wwwroot\testPublish and then made an application (right click)
> Default Web Site and navigate the physical path to the created folder
> earlier. After that I publish my solution from the Visual Studio to
> the setup above

Well, [deploying blazor server app in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-8.0) is pretty straightforward. And according to your description it seems correct. However, you haven't showed us how did you created the site in IIS within the application pool and if you have meet the [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#prerequisites) accordingly.

[image]

In my test I have done that in following steps and working accoordingly.

1. Published in local folder:

Published your blazor server app from visual studio to any folder. That should look like below:

[image]

[image]

2. Create Directory in `inetpub` under `wwwroot`

You should create new folder within the wwwroot under inetpub. That should look like as following:

[image]

3. Copy and Paste all your published items here from the initial publish folder:

[image]

4. Create new site under IIS Application pool:

[image]

[image]

5. Map your inetpub wwwroot folder with newly created site:

[image]

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please assign a port which has been occupied  before. In addition, [please refer to this official document for any further details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#iis)

Comment: Hi Farid, thanks for your time to look into my case. I've created the new application under 'Default Web Site' all my navigation 'login, home, etc" become error 404

Comment: Try to with creating new site, I am not sure why the default one not working without checking IIS configuration and SO its hard to investigate that, rather doing that, its better to try with new site with no port conflict. I think that should work if other configuration alright.

Comment: Thanks Farid, I think I'm gonna go with your solution for now until we figure it out the other alternative. Can I ask you another question? I'm creating a RedirectToLogin razor component and placed it at `NotAuthorized` tag. It work like a charm at local, but when deploy the server return error 500 and it won't redirect me to login page.

Comment: Thanks, for your response, would kindly post new question along with reproducible sample so that I can check that for you. Because, in comment its very hard to explain or investigate based on few description. I am looking forward to your new post.